# Linking value to another anywhere in blender 2.8

Tags: drivers, instances

i want to link value from one value to another. sort of instancing but for values.
for example in this case below:

[image]

monkey red and monkey green have a mix color node that both drive them to white if the mix factor is = to 1.

i want to link thoses two value so that if i change one, the other will change too and have the exact same value constantly.

i want to do this also with values in the proprety editor, N panel.. anywhere in blender really.

i heard about drivers, but every tutorials i found is to animate values depending on locations and distances, not linking one value to another.

could someone show me what is the technique ? 
i also heard about custom propreties, maybe this could also help ?

thanks

Comment: Try connecting a Value input node to the Fac of both Mix nodes. That's how you link one value to the other

Comment: cant do that its two separate materials

Comment: but htis could work with a value node inside of a nodegroup, but i want to do this anywhere anyways

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) add driver (ctrl d) to first value

2) copy driver (sorry im wrong do this at the end !!!!!)

3) paste driver to other value (sorry do this at the end !!!!!))

4) open a driver panel editor type, select the correct object otherwise the driver will not apear, also select the last step in the T panel on the left

5) go to n tab then driver tab

6) set a to scripted expression

7) the expression need to have the same name as the tab below "add input variable", so by default, "var"

8) next to "var" is a little symbol, click on it, set it to single proprety

9) create a custom proprety, in the propreties tab, you can create one in the scene tab, material tab, and object tab, and this custom proprety will appear on the N panel in the 3d viewport when the concerned object is selected, if you want the custom proprety to be not selection depentend then i advise you to create the proprety in the scene tab, or even world tab

10) we go back in the driver editor,in the n panel, and in our variable "prop" we choose the correct cathegory of where the custom proprety is

11) we need a path to the correct custom proprety we just created, so find him, right click on him, and "copy data path", then paste it in the "path" on the driver editor

12) we are done, tweak the custom proprety and the calue will change according to it, you may need to change the calue of the custom proprety in "edit" for it to correspond of the max and min value you want to tweak

---

JUST COPY AND PASTE DRIVER AT THE END ! i did it at the beginning this may be wrong

[image: https://im5.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-5-3d32e94be748.gif]

### ------------------------------------

---

in the case above its linking value for every single value possible in blender (from 0 to 1 at least)

but if you want to link value only trough the node, just use a nodegroup with an input value in it and paste it trough the materials.
in the future with everything node this will be really handy

### [image]

### ------------------------------------

Comment: oh man, this is so complex for a simple linking data process...

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do it the simple way. you put your objects as index object 1 and 2 and that's it

[image: INDEX 1 AND 2 AND ONLY NODES]

Comment: yes, if its only trough the shader editor this also work

Answer (score 0):

Custom properties allow a value to be shared and manipulated for values such as location, rotation scale.  You can create a custom value in 66 seconds.

An example appears at the bottom of this link

[How to create drivers but maintain the ability to modify the property?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/135382/how-to-create-drivers-but-maintain-the-ability-to-modify-the-property/135383#135383)

In some of the node settings you can create a function which may be called a [group].  Then reuse the group. The important point is the node system will remember the group and allow the reuse.